# Is there a module or regex in Python to convert all fonts to a uniform font? (Text is coming from Twitter)

Tags: python-3.x, text, twitter, nlp

I'm working with some text from twitter, using Tweepy. All that is fine, and at the moment I'm just looking to start with some basic frequency counts for words. However, I'm running into an issue where the ability of users to use different fonts for their tweets is making it look like some words are their own unique word, when in reality they're words that have already been encountered but in a different font/font size, like in the picture below (those words are words that were counted previously and appear in the spreadsheet earlier up).

[image]

This messes up the accuracy of the counts. I'm wondering if there's a package or general solution to make all the words a uniform font/size - either while I'm tokenizing it (just by hand, not using a module) or while writing it to the csv (using the csv module). Or any other solutions for this that I may not be considering. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact text returned to you?

Comment: Copy-and-pasting actual output is a *lot* more useful than a screenshot in most cases. Also, screenshots are hard to read by people using small displays or adaptive technologies such as screen-readers, which cuts down on the number of people who might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can (mostly) solve your problem by normalising your input, using [`unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', str)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html?highlight=unicodedata%20normalize#unicodedata.normalize).

The KC normalization form (which is what `NF` stands for) first does a "compatibility decomposition" on the text, which replaces Unicode characters which represent style variants, and then does a canonical composition on the result, so that `ñ`, which is converted to an `n` and a separate `~` diacritic by the decomposition, is then turned back into an `ñ`, the canonical composite for that character. (If you don't want the recomposition step, use `NFKD` normalisation.) See [Unicode Annex 15](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) for a more precise description, with examples.

Unicode contains a number of symbols, mostly used for mathematics, which are simply stylistic variations on some letter or digit. Or, in some cases, on several letters or digits, such as ¼ or ℆. In particular, this includes  commonly-used symbols written with font variants which have particular mathematical or other meanings, such as ℒ (the Laplace transform) and ℚ (the set of rational numbers). Canonical decomposition will strip out the stylistic information, which reduces those four examples to '1/4', 'c/u', 'L' and 'Q', respectively.

The first published Unicode standard defined a block of [Letter-like symbols block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf) in the Basic Multilingula Plane (BMP). (All of the above examples are drawn from that block.) In Unicode 3.1, complete Latin and Greek alphabets and digits were added in the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf), which  includes 13 different font variants of the 52 upper- and lower-case letters of the roman alphabet (lower and upper case), 58 greek letters in five font variants (some of which could pass for roman letters, such as  which is upsilon, not capital Y), and the 10 digits in five variants (    ). And a few loose characters which mathematicians apparently asked for.

None of these should be used outside of mathematical typography, but that's not a constraint which most users of social networks care about. So people compensate for the lack of styled text in Twitter (and elsewhere) by using these Unicode characters, despite the fact that they are not properly rendered on all devices, make life difficult for screen readers, cannot readily be searched, and all the other disadvantages of used hacked typography, such as the issue you are running into. (Some of the rendering problems are also visible in your screenshot.)

Compatibility decomposition can go a long way in resolving the problem, but it also tends to erase information which is really useful. For example, x² and H₂O become just x2 and H2O, which might or might not be what you wanted. But it's probably the best you can do.